# Expressing Irrationality of Square Root

Tags: proof-verification, rationality-testing

I fully understand the proof. However, at this stage:

$a^2 = 3b^2$

I understand that both cannot be even since they don't have common factors, but why does that lead to them both being odd? What it one was odd and one was even? Is there a proof that is not like that? Thank you.

Comment: Should the 3 not be a 2?

Comment: They are _equal_. That is what "$=$" means. You cannot have an even number $=$ an odd number.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret asking about $sqrt(3)$

Comment: OK. The most common proof along these lines regards $\sqrt{2}$ and you didn't specify, which is why I asked.

Comment: oh man u right I'm dumb to not see that sorry and thanks @Arthur

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you are worrying about whether they are even or odd.  That doesn't help directly with their divisibilty by 3.  They can't both be even and 3 is odd so they must both be odd is true.  They can't both be divisible by 5, 13, or 17 either, but those isn't particularly relevant, are they?  (or are they?)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why they never do these exercises the following way:  3|3b^2 so 3|a^2.  Three is prime so 3|a.  So 3|a^2 to an even power.  3 is prime so if 3|b^2 at all it divides it to an even power.  So 3|3b^2 to an odd power.  So 3|a^2 = 3b^2 to both an even and an odd power which is impossible.  That seems so much simpler and straightforwad (albeit not classically antiquated) then the usual ad infinitem.  Which gets hard if you are trying to show something like the square root of 12 is irrational.

Comment: I mean seriously, isn't the following a thousand times easier:  Let $\sqrt{n} = a/b$ where $a/b$ is in lowest terms.  So $a$ and $b$ have no prime factors in common.  So $a^2/b^2$ will have no prime factors in common.  Thus $(a/b)^2$ can not be an integer unless $b = 1$.  Thus $\sqrt{n} = a/b = a \implies n = a^2$.  So only perfect squares have rational square roots (which are integers).  Why the heck don't they teach it that way?

Comment: " They can't both be divisible by 5, 13, or 17 either, but those isn't particularly relevant, are they? (or are they?)"  In a way, they are.  If $p \ne 3$ then if $p|3b^2 \implies p|a$ and $p|b$ which is impossible as a/b is in lowest terms.  This is true for *all* prime p so the only possible prime divisors of a and b are $3$.  So $\sqrt 3 =3^n/3^m = 3^{n-m}$ and $3 = 3^{2(n-m)} = 3^1$ so $2(n-m) = 1$ and $n-m \in \mathbb Z$ which is clearly impossible

Answer (score 1):

If one of them is  odd, the other is too:

- If $a$ is odd, $a^2$ is too, i.e. $3b^2$ is odd, which implies $b$ is odd.
- If $b$ is odd, $3b^2=a^2$ is, hence $a$ is odd.

In either case, both $a$ and $b$ are odd.

Comment: You are missing the point that $\frac{a}{b}$ is assumed earlier to be in lowest terms so it cannot be that $a$ and $b$ are both even.

Comment: @Solomonoff's Secret: ??? I didn't even (:o)) mention the word ‘even’!

Comment: Sorry, never mind. You didn't address the case that $a$ and $b$ are both even but the OP says (s)he understands that this case cannot be.